# Normalized Database schema of quiz in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am little confusing for building schema of quiz

In this I have to upload many questions and having four options each option contains textbox and corresponding checkbox that denotes for right answer. if admin select one checkbox that could be right answer.

Note:- In some cases I have uploaded many option 6 to 7 and answers might be 2 or 3 are correct and admin will click on many checkboxes

[image]

Can anyone helping in schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems fairly straight forward. You just have three tables, one for quizzes, one for questions and one for answers. Something like this:

Quizzes

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+
| id |    name     |   description   |
+----+-------------+-----------------+
|  1 | Sample Quiz | An example quiz |
+----+-------------+-----------------+
```

Questions

```
+----+---------+------------+
| id | quiz_id |  question  |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 |       1 | Question 1 |
+----+---------+------------+
```

Answers

```
+----+-------------+----------+------------+
| id | question_id |  answer  | is_correct |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+
|  1 |           1 | Answer 1 |          0 |
|  2 |           1 | Answer 2 |          1 |
|  3 |           1 | Answer 3 |          0 |
|  4 |           1 | Answer 4 |          0 |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+
```

This schema will support as many quizzes as you need, each with any number of questions and each question can have any number of answers.

Comment: where answer1 ,answe2,answe3,answe4 are stored in which table

Comment: can you please add one record in your database  that will be more understood